# Procedure for changing frequency of Nano or similar

Tags: arduino-nano, atmega328, frequency

I need to get interrupts at one of three specific rates: 1920, 2000, and 2400 per sec, at a fairly high precision (~10 ppm). I've asked about this on Electronics but I think here might be more appropriate.

I can't use the standard 16MHz with internal timers, since 16MHz / 2400 (for example) gives 66666.666... counts.

I would use an external standard, but I don't seem to be able to find one that fits the need. Something small and precise at 48KHz / 96KHz etc would be fine.

Alternatively, I could swap the crystal / resonator for one running at 18.432MHz, which divides evenly by those freqs and shouldn't tax a 328p. Can I even do that on a Nano, or some clone / comparable, with the required 10ppm?

-- extra removed --

Comment: Sure you can swap the crystal. The maximum is 20MHz, so 18.whatever is well within the capabilities. You'll have to adjust the board settings to match of course (F_CPU).

Comment: Whoo, 10 ppm, quite a challenge! Did you consider the initial precision, the influence of temperature and voltage/current, drift, ageing? You might need something better than a simple crystal, for example an [oven-controlled crystal oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oven).

Comment: Oh, and of course the jitter due to different numbers of clocks for instructions, leading to different interrupt latency.

Comment: @thebusybee - I know 10ppm is asking a lot. If I could find a reasonably priced TXCO at 48 or 96 KHz in a small package I'd do that for sure. As for jitter, a small amount is OK in exchange for longer-term (~30 msec) accuracy.

Comment: You could use a TXCO of higher frequency and divide it. -- All this seems to call for a more hardware based solution, perhaps a CPLD or FPGA. Why do you need such an accuracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an internal timer.

You are using interrupts, and you are probably aware that interrupt
handling inevitably incurs some jitter. Thus, if you do not mind an
extra single CPU cycle of jitter, you could reconfigure the timer on
each interrupt in order to control the *average* interrupt period.

Here is how I would do it, with Timer 1 running in normal mode (CTC mode
would require an extra operation):

```cpp
// Interrupt period in units of 1/2^16 CPU cycles.
// For 2.4 kHz, that is 16000/2.4*65536 = 436906666.666...
uint32_t interrupt_period = 436906667;

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    // Update the timer for the next interrupt.
    static uint32_t accumulator;
    accumulator += interrupt_period;
    OCR1A = accumulator >> 16;

    // The periodic task goes here...
}

void setup() {
    // Configure Timer 1.
    TCCR1A = 0;            // normal mode
    TCCR1B = _BV(CS10);    // clock @ F_CPU
    TIMSK1 = _BV(OCIE1A);  // enable COMPA interrupt
}

void loop(){}
```

Here, `accumulator` is a 32-bit extension of the timer's output compare
register. The upper 16 bits are copied into the actual timer
register, whereas the lower 16 bits ensure that the accumulated
error never exceeds one cycle.

This way of updating the timer should only take about 2 µs per
interrupt. It is a constant time operation, so it doesn't add extra
jitter to your task, other than the single cycle of jitter induced by
rounding to the next edge of the CPU clock.

There are a couple of caveats though:

1. This can only work on an Arduino clocked off a crystal (e.g., a
   Micro). Those clocked off a ceramic resonator (Uno...) would be too
   unstable in frequency to meet your 10 ppm requirement.
2. Even though a crystal is more than stable enough to meet your
   requirement, it is unlikely to be accurate enough. You will then need
   to calibrate it, e.g. by outputting a PWM signal (`analogWrite()`)
   into a frequency meter. Then adjust the variable `interrupt_period`
   according to the measured clock frequency.

---

**Edit**: I added the timer configuration to the code, and here comes an
explanation of how this code works.

Think of the timer as a digital alarm clock. It measures time in units
of CPU cycles instead of hours and minutes. It rolls over every
2<sup>16</sup> cycles instead of every 1440 minutes. But it is
otherwise a regular alarm clock. It has two alarms called “COMPA” and
“COMPB”, but you only need one. In order to perform a periodic task, you
turn the alarm on and, every time it rings, you advance the alarm time
by the required period. That is, you set:

new alarm time = previous alarm time + task period

Note that the addition has to be computed modulo the roll-over period of
your clock : 1440 minutes for a regular alarm clock,
2<sup>16</sup> cycles for the timer. Thankfully, the arithmetics on
unsigned numbers do this automatically.

Now, lets say the task period is 43 minutes and 35 seconds,
but the alarm can only be set with a resolution of one minute. What you
can do is compute the “ideal” alarm time on paper (this is the
`accumulator` variable), and truncate it to the resolution of the clock
when setting the alarm. If you start at 00:00:00, you will compute the
next ideal time to be 00:43:35 and set the alarm to 00:43. When it
rings, you add the period to the previously computed time, you get
01:27:10, and you set the alarm to 01:27. Etc. Here is the list of the
alarm times as computed and as actually set on the clock:

```
computed  set
───────────────
00:00:00  00:00
00:43:35  00:43
01:27:10  01:27
02:10:45  02:10
...
```

Note that, even though the limited resolution of the alarm setting
creates some jitter, the *average* task period is still exactly
43 minutes and 35 seconds.

The code I wrote above does exactly the same. The “ideal” alarm time is
computed as a fractional number of CPU cycles, written down in binary
fixed point, with 16-bits on each side of the radix point. In hex, it is
1A0A.AAAB CPU cycles. The computed alarm times are multiples of this
period, whereas the times actually written to OCR1A are the same
truncated to an integer:

```
computed   set
───────────────
1A0A.AAAB  1A0A
3415.5556  3415
4E20.0001  4E20
682A.AAAC  682A
...
```

Comment: Thanks much for this, but, sorry, I don't get how it works. I gather there's some initial setting up of the counter that you don't show? It seems that we're outputting wildly variable values to OCR1A: 1A0A, 3415, 4E20, 682A etc. What's going on?

Comment: @JimMack: See expanded answer.

Comment: Very nice. I knew that somehow I should implement Bresenham's algorithm to average away the error, but I couldn't see a way to do it. I'll ask another question based on this, to try to solve another issue.